# How do I write a Prometheus query that returns the value of a label?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm making a Grafana dashboard and want a panel that reports the latest version of our app. The version is reported as a label in the `app_version_updated` (say) metric like so:

```
app_version_updated{instance="eu99",version="1.5.0-abcdefg"}
```

I've tried a number of Prometheus queries to extract the version label *as a string* from the latest member of this time series, to no effect.

For example, the query

```
count(app_version_updated) by (version)
```

returns a `{version="1.5.0-abcdefg"}` element with a value of `1`. When put in a Grafana dashboard in a single value panel, this doesn't display the version *string* but instead the count value (`1`).

How can I construct a Prometheus query that returns the version string?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My answer tries to elaborate on Carl's answer. I assume that the GUI layout may have changed a little since 2016, so it took me while to find the "name" option.

Assuming you have a metric as follows:

```
# HELP db2_prometheus_adapter_info Information on the state of the DB2-Prometheus-Adapter
# TYPE db2_prometheus_adapter_info gauge
db2_prometheus_adapter_info{app_state="UP") 1.0
```

and you would like to show the value of the label `app_state`.

Follow these steps:

- Create a "SingleStat" visualization.
- Go to the "Queries" tab:

  - Enter the name (here `db2_prometheus_adapter_info`) of the metric.
  - Enter the label name as the legend using the `{{[LABEL]}}` notation  (here `{{app_state}}`).
  - Activate the "instant" option.

[image: Settings in Queries Tab]

- Go to the "Visualization" tab:

  - Choose the value "Name" under "Value - Stat".

[image: Setting in Visualization Tab]

Note on the "Instant" setting: This setting switches from a range query to a simplified query only returning the most recent value of the metric (also see [What does the "instant" checkbox in grafana graphs based on prometheus do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728031/what-does-the-instant-checkbox-in-grafana-graphs-based-on-prometheus-do)). If not activated, the panel will show an error as soon as there is more than one distinct value for the label in the history of the metric. For a "normal" metric you would remedy this by choosing "current" in the "Value - Stat" option. But doing so here prevents your label value to be shown.

Comment: SingleStat is deprecated in v7 and removed in v8.  It was replaced with [Stat](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/stat-panel/).

Answer (score 17):

We recently added support for displaying the serie name as a value in the single stat panel (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4740). So you have to run our nightly build until we release 4.0.

Just make sure the query returns one serie and you can use the "name" value in the dropdown under Options -> big value.Then you can format the string using the legend formater. Ex {{job}} would return "node" as a serie name.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me.

```
label_values(my_metric{type= "xxx", another_label="xxx"},target_label)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I what field do you put this, because it can't be processed by PromQL ?

Comment: Yes, "label_values" function does not exist in PromQL. It is a grafana thing that I used to create a variable in the dashbord forexample.

Comment: explain this more please

Comment: label_values can only be used on the variables screen in a dashboard in grafana https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#:~:text=The%20label_values%20function%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20support%20queries%2C%20so%20you%20can%20use%20these%20variables%20in%20conjunction%20with%20the%20query_result%20function%20to%20filter%20variable%20queries.

Answer (score 9):

With `Stat` visualization in Grafana 8+, you can set the legend to the intended label name and then change the `Stat Styles -> Text Mode` to `Name`
[image]

Answer (score 6):

While most of @marcus-rickert's answer is still valid in Grafana 7, there is some change.
The 'Stat' 'Name' field seems to be gone, instead in the 'Field' panel, you can set the 'Display name' to the label you want to show.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus doesn't have any functions that return strings, what you're looking for is for a Grafana singlestat to be able to display a label value - which it unfortunately doesn't support yet.

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/5094 tracks this.

Comment: This feature is now implemented

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to get all the various values of a label from Prometheus to put into a variable in Grafana. I used this simple query to populate my varialbe Drop-Down list:

`label_values(myLabelName)`

This returned the expected "value01", "value02" etc

Comment: yes I agree with this. It works for me.

Comment: How to get a single label, when bunch of labels get returned by ```label_values``` function

Answer (score 2):

Another update on very latest kube-prometheus-stack using grafana 8.0.3. I still faced this issue, for me in a Bar gauge I still had this issue in scenarios where it only returned 1 value, but with 2+ values the Legend field works OK.

My solution:

Go to *Edit Panel*, find *Display Name*, type

> ${__field.labels.insertYourLegendValueHere}

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` followed by the label you trying to get the value from.

For example:

```
sum(windows_cpu_info{instance="$hostname"}) by l2_cache_size
```

In this case, `l2_cache_size` is the label I wanted to get the returned value from.