# Loki LogQL topk aggregate function

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I've started shipping traefik access logs (in JSON) to Grafana Loki and wanted to visualize the top 3 ClientHosts.
This is the LogQL I have written for this but it returns all ClientHosts for the selected time range instead of only the top 3.
What am I missing?

```
topk(3, sum by (ClientHost)(count_over_time({filename="/var/log/traefik/access-json.log"}|json[5m])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "Explore" on Grafana? Do not forget to select the following option:

```
Query type = Instant
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this answer - would you mind adding a quick explanation for the differences between instant vs. range query types? And if possible could you link to documentation? (I find it very difficult to find good grafana+loki+logql documentation myself!)

Comment: "Instant" will show only the last value of your query and "range" will show results for the entire time range. I think here you can find more detailed answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728031/what-does-the-instant-checkbox-in-grafana-graphs-based-on-prometheus-do