# How to find the p99 in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, victoriametrics

I need to find out the P99 of the Prometheus metrics within the time range given in the timepicker grafana.

Example:

Here I have taken, MySQL Transaction History metric, this will show the innodb transaction history size.

```
(max_over_time(mysql_info_schema_innodb_metrics_transaction_trx_rseg_history_len{service_name=~"$service_name"}[$interval]))
```

Output:

[image]

Analyzing the graph, we can observe a gradual increase followed by a sudden drop in activity.

**My goal is to determine the P99 percentile for this metric within the specified time range (from 10:30:00 to 13:30:00 in grafana timepicker) and present the results in a statistical format.**

Answer (score 2):

The following query returns 99th [percentile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) for the given metric on the selected time range:

```
quantile_over_time(0.99, mysql_info_schema_innodb_metrics_transaction_trx_rseg_history_len{service_name=~"$service_name"}[$interval])
```

This query must be put inside `instant query` in Grafana in order to return only a single result instead of a graph - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728031/what-does-the-instant-checkbox-in-grafana-graphs-based-on-prometheus-do) for more details on instant query.

See [docs for quantile_over_time() function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#quantile_over_time).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, @valyala. I experimented with quantile_over_time() using various time ranges and managed to display individual statistics. However, I noticed that the p99 value(grafana) differs from manual calculations. Any insights on why there is a discrepancy?

Comment: Grafana performs its calculations based on data points it receives from the datasource (Prometheus or VictoriaMetrics). The datasource returns _calculated_ datapoints at the requested timestamps `start`, `start+step`, `start+2*step`, ..., `end`, where `start` and `end` are starting and ending timestamps for the selected time range, while `step` is the step between adjacent points displayed on the graph. See https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query . This means that Grafana may miss some raw samples, while `quantile_over_time()` takes into account all the raw samples.

Comment: Yo can get raw samples from Prometheus and VictoriaMetrics for particular time series on the particular time range via `/api/v1/query` endpoint as described in the following article - https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639