# Prometheus get sum of label values of all metric entries

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have multiple trivy result entries in prometheus that look like this:

```
trivy_vulnerability{critical="0", high="12"} 0
```

Is there a way in prometheus where i retrieve all the trivy_vulnerability entries and get a total sum of the total high cve count?

Comment: Could you elaborate please: metric `trivy_vulnerability` has 12 as label `high` and this means that you have 12 high vulnerabilities?

Comment: Yes, excuses that indeed means there are 12 high vulnerabilties found.

We have many entries with different numbers.
We want to know the total amount of high vulnerabilities (same with critical)

Comment: You can't do it using promQL. And frankly speaking - it's misuse of metrics.

Comment: If grafana you could try to use [label_values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61914010/21363224), but I'm not sure if grafana will allow you to aggregate results in some way.

Comment: Your issue is that your label (`critical`, `high`) values (`0`,`12`) should be represented as metric values. Something of the form `trivy_vulnerability{severity="high"} 12` and `trivy_vulnerability{severity="critical"} 0`. If that were the structure of your metrics, then you **would** be able to aggregate (sum) values. What are you using to produce the metrics?

Comment: I am looking for this too, to no avail. Seems to be such an obvious use case, and yet there are no clear solutions. In my case I spawn subprocesses, and want to aggregate the number of messages sent by all subprocesses. It's the same metric, but with different `job` label value, for example `messages_sent(job="faust-545")` and so on.

Comment: @Karolis, I don't see how what you described related to this question. This question is about attempt to get some workaround for blatant misuse of labels by some exporter. In your case is looks like a task for rather simple aggregation. Consider asking separate question if it is in fact not.