# Set prometheus metric to return datetime instead of a float

Tags: python, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator, grafana-api

```
self.add_metric(
            prom.Gauge,
            "date_to_catch",
            "The timestamp when the event happened",
        )
@property
    def date_to_catch(self):
        return self.get_metric("date_to_catch")

def get_the_date(self):
self.date_to_catch.set(datetime.now().timestamp())
```

I would like that the metric is returning a datetime instead of a timestamp. I know that `metric.set()` returns a float, how can I force/hack it to return a datetime? I have tried this but it was showing an error since the retun should be float:

```
self.date_to_catch.set(datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime.now().timestamp()).replace(microsecond=0).strftime("%c"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus' metric can take as values only numbers. And I believe in your situation metric with the value of UNIX timestamp is perfectly fine.

Then, you can simply configure your panel to show this value as time.

For example, this can be done with Transformation *Convert field type*. It will convert timestamp in milliseconds into human readable date time.

Example of query `timestamp(up) * 1000` (multiplication by 1000 to convert timestamp in seconds into timestamp in milliseconds):
[image]

Comment: I consider again that:  The value only updates and the key (label) will not be exported again. It is a good way.

Comment: @markalex thank you for you response :) I tried it but I was getting date since 1970-01-20 and I think it's the default  UNIX time. Do you, please, have an idea how to transform that to be the actual date? I can see in the screenshot you posted that you are getting the correct years, but I don't know how can I make it.

Comment: oh actually the value you are getting is the metric timing, however I want to specify a specific time (which is current time) that should be caught by matric as value.

Comment: @YosraMH, you need to multiply by 1000, to get correct date: Grafana expects milliseconds. Regarding my example: yes I in fact show timestamp of the metric, and not the value. But it's due to lack of metric with the value of timestamp. In your case `date_to_catch *1000` will work exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send the string date time with labels of the metrics. Values only can be integer or float. But, if you send it with the label, you can see the human-readable date time.

**Defining metrics with readable date time label:**

```
custom_metric = Gauge(
    "custom_metric_data",
    "custom metric data as a metric",
    ["data", "readable_datetime"]
)
```

**Adding the human readable date time into the metric label + sending float unix timestamp:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def get_current_unix_timestamp():
  return float(time.time())

now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

# Set the metric value with labels + value is unixtimestamp in float
custom_metric.labels(data=data, readable_datetime=now).set(get_current_unix_timestamp())
```

**Metric Output on Prometheus Exporter:**

```
custom_metric{data="data",readable_datetime="2023-10-17T10:49:18"} 1.697532558e+09
```

Comment: thank you for the response :) But then the output in grafana will be 1.697532558e+09 right? It will remain timestamp right? I'm using grafana dashboard to project the output of the metric

Comment: No. On the Grafana part, Promql should be like that: topk(1, sort_desc(custom_metric{...})). To get the latest timestamp data. Then, Query > Options > Legend should be {{readable_datetime}}. Sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57850590/6146801

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS, unless you sure that time stamp in the label will change very rarely! This approach has potential to balloon up cardinality of your metric and have extreme consequences on the performance and storage taken of the Prometheus.

Comment: Right, Prometheus will export each timestamp change. But, while coding, if you check whether the data changes or not, it exports data ONLY when the data changes. So, you don't have many lines of data. The IMPORTANT point is exporting value with timestamp when DATA updates.

Comment: @ÖmerSezer every unique label set results in separated time series inside Prometheus. If timestamp changes often, even though at every time only a single metric is exposed, Prometheus will store and process them separately, and this might result in severe performance issues (if timestamps rarely change, like once a week, this should not be an issue though)

Comment: @markalex I got your point, thanks.