# How to get the label of "boolean" metrics from PromQL to Grafana Vizualization

Tags: prometheus, grafana, transformation, metrics, promql

## Background

The main problem is working with these style of metrics:

```
some_state_metric{name="something", state="active"} = 1
some_state_metric{name="something", state="inactive"} = 0
some_state_metric{name="something", state="failing"} = 0
```

> I don't know what they are called, but I refer to them as "boolean metrics" or "state metrics"

They track the state of something overtime by using 1 and 0 as booleans to indicate if the state is active or not.

### Why do they exist?

As far as I can tell, this is used to work around the fact that PromQL/Prometheus don't have valid text/enum values for metrics, only numbers.
The two options an implementer has, is to have the value represent a state... (as in 0=null, 1=active, 2=inactive, 3=failing)

> The problem with that solution is that it doesn't translate well to any PromQL queries that use labels as important partitioning indicators.

...Or, as seems to be the norm, representing each state as a separate label and then using a boolean value to indicate which state is active.

> This can also be used to represent "combined" states.

### Examples of This in the wild

- Unix Node Exporter's systemd `node_systemd_unit_state`
- Kubelet Pod Phase `kube_pod_status_phase`

## Can't use em'

Sadly there is no native way in prometheus to represent these in a useful format.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525891/how-do-i-write-a-prometheus-query-that-returns-the-value-of-a-label)

I wish there was a special function that would work with this type of type of metric:

```
group(boolean_metric(some_state_metric, "state")) by(name)
```

resulting in the data-frame of:

```
vector<something>(1708277100, "active")
vector<something>(1708277101, "active")
vector<something>(1708277102, "active")
vector<something>(1708277103, "active")
vector<something>(1708277104, "failing")
```

> **Don't take this data-frame representation as gospel,**
> I know prometheus works on the vector principle, so there needs to be
> a direction (time i think) and a magnitude (the value I think) it then
> groups them with a specific tag
> but i have no idea how to convey that information, or what it looks like internally

It basically returns the value of the label (state) where every value is equal to 1, partitioned on the instance label.

***But no, this doesn't exist.***

## Why?

I want to use the [state timeline](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/state-timeline/) and the [status history](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/status-history/) visualization to represent the states.

The problem is both of these have no way to specify an alternate `Value` field.
They also expect the data-frame (time series) format, so I can't use tables really.

They both expect a unique discrete value returned by a query to map to a state, so 1 and 0 don't really work.

## Experiments

I did try to do something with multiplying a given state by an offset:

```
some_state_metric{state="active"} * 10
  or
some_state_metric{state="inactive"} * 100
  or
some_state_metric{state="failing"} * 1000
```

You could then map `10 -> active` and `100 -> inactive` and `1000 -> failing`

But I struggled with the combining of the queries, (I think I am doing it wrong).
this is also "bad" because it involves multiple queries when, really, 1 should do.

## Question

How do I convert a prometheus "state metric" / "boolean metric" into a format that can be used with the Grafana *state timeline* or the *status history*?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out something

With the new [partition by values](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#partition-by-values) transformation!

It was actually pretty simple (though it did take me some time)

> I'll be using the `node_systemd_unit_state` from the systemd module of the node exporter.

## Steps

### Query

First step is to group the labels we want:

> Remember to set the Format to "Table"

```
group(node_systemd_unit_state{} == 1) by(name, state)
```

[image: PromQL]

### Transformation

Second Step is to remove the "Value" from the results and only keep the `Time`, `name` and `state`
You do this with the [Filter fields by name](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#filter-fields-by-name) transformation.

You can use the GUI to set them, or you can specify the regex `/^(?!Value)/`, which should remove the `Value` field

Then you **partition** on the `name` field with the [Partition by values](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#partition-by-values).

> Remember to set "As Frame Name"

[image: Grafana Transformations]

### Visualization

Now just set the colours of your "Value Mappings" to the desired representation, and there you go!

[image: Value Mappings]

### Status Timeline (Additional)

You probably want to set the "Minimum Interval" to something like `30m`, `1h` or `1d` depending on the scale you are working on.

Comment: I like this solution better than what is usually done, as you described in your Experiments part of question.